# Explanation of the use of this command (Beautiful soup and re.compile)

Tags: python, dictionary, python-re

I have the following command which I am struggling to break down and explain for teaching purposes.

```
images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
```

**The whole code for this function is:**

```
def imagescrape():
    result_images=[]
    html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
    for image in images:
        result_images.append("https:"+image['src']+'\n') #concatenation!
    return result_images
```

Of course, we know that images is the variable that stores the result of the command.
I also know the result of bs.find_all (bs being the object created and .find all is the method being used to find all instances of the 'img' tag).

The find_all method takes two arguments.  One is 'img' (this could be, correct me if wrong, any string). The second argument appears to be a **dictionary** and here I am slightly lost:

```
'src':re.compile('.jpg')}
```

From research, I understand the following:

"src" is the key in the dictionary
and the next part:

```
re.compile('.jpg')}
```

is the value part of the dictionary.

But why has a dictionary been used?

Also, more importantly, what, in this specific situation, is re.compile('jpg')} actually doing in this case? What is being returned? And why is it in a dictionary being used? I would need a very student-friendly beginner, broken down explanation please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a dictionary.
One of the following options can be used.

`images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})`
Is the equivalent of the following, which uses named arguments.
`images = bs.find_all('img', attrs={'src': re.compile('.jpg')})`

`images = bs.find_all('img', **{'src':re.compile('.jpg')})`
Is identical to the following.
`images = bs.find_all('img', src=re.compile('.jpg'))`

The expression `re.compile('.jpg')` returns a regular expression object, which can be used several times or later. It's a modular approach to regular expressions.
Keep in mind that some characters have a deeper meaning within regular expressions. In this case this concerns the character '.'. I think you should use `'\.jpg'`. Otherwise, it would match the meaning of any character followed by jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Beautifulsoup answered this in their own documentation:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression

It boils down to regular expressions which find_all consumes

Comment: Please see updated answer - could you suggest a fix to the above. Also, this answer doesn't really explain the output in my specific case and how the dicitonary, re.compile is being used. My question is more about re.compile as opposed to findall..